# How can I make Visual Studio 2010 show all available events for RadioButton

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm running Visual Studio 2010, maybe it applies for other versions as well. When I'm in the designer and looking at the events for the RadioButton, the MouseDoubleClick event is not there:

[image: Visual Studio 2010 Designer Events]

However if I go to code view and looks at the events for the RadioButton there, I can see the MouseDoubleClick event:

[image]

It seems like VS designer is only showing the inherited events, and not the ones that is directly implemented in the RadioButton class. How can I make all of them show up in the designer?

**Edit:** As both Hans Passant (comment to the question) and lomed (accepted answer) points out, this is intentionally hidden. I'm using ReSharper, and that is probably why it shows up in IntelliSense, something that lomed pointed out as well in the comments of his accepted answer.

```
[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public event MouseEventHandler MouseDoubleClick;
```

Comment: It is the exact opposite.  When is the last time you operated a program and thought "hmm, let's double-click that radio button and see what happens?"  Which is why it is intentionally hidden, no user will *ever* discover this unless you write a manual.

Comment: Yes, I learned from @lomed answer that it is hidden by intention. You are right, usually it doesn't make sense to double click a radiobutton. Depending on the context it could make sense in rare situations. I'm showing a form where the user can select between three radiobuttons, accepting the selected radiobutton by pressing the Ok button or doubleclicking the radiobutton.

Comment: _accepting the selected radiobutton by pressing the Ok button or doubleclicking the radiobutton._ Argh. Who would do that? Feels unpredicable to me..

Comment: @TaW Yes, maybe I have the wrong idea. What would be most user friendly, most intuitive..? User shall select between three options, and then the user needs to confirm the selection. After the confirmation that specific selection is "executed".

Comment: You have an OK button - what else do you need? Maybe a friendly text that points out what he okays..but otherwise I would keep it simple. You could enable the Button after the choice has been made, if you can/want to disable all radiobuttons. But if one choice is default go for the Button only!

Comment: @TaW Keep it simple is a good advice... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Object Browser` or in code-meta-data (Right Click-> Go To Definition or F12) or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

in `Object Browser`(F2) Set enable "Show Hidden Type And Member" (see: [Did you know… You can hide or show hidden members and types in the Object Browser?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/05/14/did-you-know-you-can-hide-or-show-hidden-members-and-types-in-the-object-browser-215.aspx), and [Viewing the Structure of Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whks02wf.aspx))
[image: RadioButton.MouseDobleClick in object explorer]

The way it hid the event you can see in his `Signature`:

```
[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public event MouseEventHandler MouseDoubleClick;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. So does this mean that if the Event is marked with the attribute [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)] it will not show up in the designer and there is no simple way of making it show up there... Then the solution is to browse with the Object Browser instead..?

Comment: @jmelhus yes, I think so.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Let's see if there are some other views /answers on this topic. If not I will mark you answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @jmelhus, With me also intellisense does not appear. You use ReSharper, right?

Comment: Yes that is true. Aha, so it is hidden in the regular intellisense as well. It is Resharper that provides it...